# How to add shortcut keys to netbeans menu bar?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I am developing a Netbeans RCP application, in this we needed a custom menu bar so i created a **XML layer** file, and in it i created a folder called **Test** in **Menu bar** folder.But unfortunately i do not know how to add shortcuts to it Eg: like **Alt+f** which opens the pop options of **File** menu.
I am able to add actions and shortcuts to sub menus created under **Test** but i am unable to add shortcuts to the **Test** menu itself.I want the menu to open its pop up with **Alt+B** command.Could someone give many ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding a Mnemonic key to the Menu **"Test"** by adding **displayname** attribute to the **"Test"** folder in **layer.xml** file

```
<folder name= "Menu">
   <folder name="Test"> 
      <attr name="displayName" bundlevalue="com.test.MenuBar.Bundle#Menu/Test"/>
   </folder>
</folder>
```

and in the module's **Bundle.properties** I added

> Menu/Test=Te&st

Here the character after **&** will be taken as the Mnemonic key i.e character **"S"**. So if you invoke **"Alt+S"** the **"Test"** menu pop-up will be displayed